# I am looking for an equation that expresses Vout in terms of Vin

Tags: transistors

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqLYqd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What do you think it is? Show your math.

Comment: Vin of 1V is a bit low to turn the two BE's on. Which is fortunate, because you have no load on the emitter of Q2.

Comment: I understand that, at Vin>1.4V , the current gain in Q2 would be extremely large. I am just looking for an expression for the collector output voltage for the first stage transistor in terms of input voltage Vin

Comment: It would be the same as the collector current for a single transistor with half the BE input voltage.

Answer (score 1):

The equation is:

```
 Vout = Vcc.
```

Explanation:

While 0.7 volt is the nominal drop across a forward biased silicon junction, current does flow below that voltage. So it's likely that Q2 will be destroyed - a toss-up whether it finishes short or open circuit. Then, if Q1 still has a path to common, its base-emitter junction would fry, if not already fried. When the smoke clears, there will likely be no path for Vcc to common and so VM1 will show Vcc.

Comment: You forgot to put the answer as an equation. I edited that in for you. If you disagree with the edit, you could use the "rollback" link in the "edited ..." page. ;-)

Comment: cheers mate! I suppose he might have a low-Z meter...

Comment: -1:  I don't understand why you think that it is likely that Q2 will be destroyed with the 1V input voltage.  Q2's collector current should be less than 0.1mA for that input voltage.

Answer (score 1):

In the following, the Early effect is ignored and we assume active mode.

For Q2, we have:

$$v_{BE2} = V_T \ln \frac{\beta i_{B2}}{I_S}$$

$$i_{B2} = \frac{i_{C1}}{\alpha} = \frac{I_S}{\alpha}e^{\frac{v_{BE1}}{V_T}}$$

$$\Rightarrow v_{BE2} = v_{BE1} + V_T \ln (1 + \beta)$$

By KVL:

$$v_{IN} = v_{BE1} + v_{BE2} = 2v_{BE1} + V_T \ln (1 + \beta)$$

Thus:

$$\Rightarrow v_{BE1} = \dfrac{v_{IN} - V_T \ln (1 + \beta)}{2}$$

For Q1, we have:

$$i_{C1} = I_S e^{\frac{v_{BE1}}{V_T}} = \dfrac{I_S}{\sqrt{1+\beta}}e^{\frac{v_{IN}}{2}} $$

$$v_{OUT} = 15V - i_{C1} \cdot 100\Omega$$

Thus, and finally:

$$\Rightarrow  v_{OUT} = 15V - \dfrac{I_S\cdot 100\Omega}{\sqrt{1+\beta}}e^{\frac{v_{IN}}{2V_T}} $$

Comment: Thankyou!                                                  this is EXACTLY what i was looking for, and you managed to do it without any smart-alecky comments or mocking my profound ignorance.